# ajax request in extjs always executes success

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl, extjs, cgi

I have a ajax request, where i have code for both success and failure

```
success: function(my_response) {
},
failure: function(my_response) {
}
```

I am using Perl CGI in the server to handle the Ajax request, it prints below string when there is a failure

```
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
print "{success: false, errors: {response: 'Query Failed -- Please check the syntax'}}";
exit
```

In the firebug, i can see the above response. But, my browser is always executing the code in success. Is there anything wrong in the way i am handling the ajax request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending JSON message with status code 200 which is considered as success. The fact that this JSON message contains some custom structure with an error message is not something that extjs is capable of knowing. You could either send a 500 HTTP status code from your server or simply use an if condition in your success handler like this:

```
success: function(my_response) {
   if (my_response.success) {
       alert('it worked!');
   } else {
       alert('oops, something went wrong: ' + my_response.errors.response);
   }
}
```

Also readapt the content type to what you are actually sending:

```
print "Content-Type: application/json\n\n";
```

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, your success handler is missing a call to `Ext.util.JSON.decode()` to decode the response from the server. That code up there would break.

Comment: @Jaitsu, oh, yes indeed, I though that based on the content type extjs would do this automatically (as jquery does). Please feel free to update my answer and include this valuable information.

Comment: Ext is not only capable of deciphering the status code in the JSON, the JsonReader class is specifically designed to do so via the successProperty config.  A 500 response (server error) is different than a 200 response with success:false (server OK, but validation error in the response).

Comment: As mentioned by Jaitsu, if you are manually handling your response then you must decode it first (Ext.util.JSON.decode would work). If you go through the store/proxy/reader infrastructure that Ext provides you then the JsonReader will handle that for you automatically.